# SQL Left Join returns less than expected

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a database, and I need to get data that is on the table PEDIDOC mixed in with FALTANTE, but I need to do a left join because I need ALL the data in PEDIDOC even if there is no matching FALTANTE. I have triple checked and all information is inputed correctly and everything is there, if I just do Select * FROM pedidoc I get what I expect when I filter it in Excel, but when I do my left joins, then there are productos missing.

Here is the query

```
SELECT
        `pedidoc`.`fecha`,
        `pedidoc`.`IdPedido`, `pedidoc`.`plaza`, `pedidoc`.`IdProducto`,
        `pedidoc`.`Categoria`,`pedidoc`.`Pedido`,`faltante`.`faltante`
FROM `pedidoc`
        LEFT JOIN `caducidad` ON `pedidoc`.`IdProducto`=`faltante`.`IdProducto`
GROUP BY `pedidoc`.`fecha`, `pedidoc`.`IdProducto`
```

Here is the database

```
CREATE TABLE Faltante (
    IdProducto DECIMAL(17,0) NOT NULL,
    Plaza VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Fecha VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Faltante INT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(IdProducto) REFERENCES Producto(IdProducto),
    UNIQUE(IdProducto, Fecha, Plaza)
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE pedidoc (
    IdProducto DECIMAL(17,0) NOT NULL,
    IdPedido VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Plaza VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Fecha VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Categoria VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Pedido INT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(IdProducto) REFERENCES Producto(IdProducto),
    UNIQUE(IdProducto, Fecha, Plaza)
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

The data that it does return is correct (took some random samples) but it is missing more than half of the data in pedidoc.

What is wrong with my query?

FYI I am running Windows 8 on my test machine and a WAMP stack.

Saludos,
Gustavo

EDIT> Here is the table I get for the "first" day. The problem is that it only takes one product per day, when there is really *one product per day per plaza.* There is supposed to be one product list, almost the same for each plaza, but for Monterrey it only shows 2, instead of all the products

```
fecha           IdPedido    plaza   IdProducto  Categoria   Pedido  caducidad
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  4111    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7920    Bigdonuts   406 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7921    Bigdonuts   425 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7922    Bigdonuts   712 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7923    Bigdonuts   454 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7924    Bigdonuts   31  0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7925    Bigdonuts   11  0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7926    Bigdonuts   147 0
01/01/2012  2590100-10  Monterrey   7928    Bigdonuts   128 0
01/01/2012  2590100-10  Monterrey   7929    Bigdonuts   70  0
01/01/2012  2590090-30  Reynosa 7931    Big Donuts  12  0
01/01/2012  2590090-30  Reynosa 7932    Big Donuts  154 0
01/01/2012  2590090-30  Reynosa 7933    Big Donuts  23  0
01/01/2012  2590090-30  Reynosa 7934    Big Donuts  169 0
01/01/2012  2590090-30  Reynosa 7935    Big Donuts  50  0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7936    Bigdonuts   352 0
01/01/2012  2590100-10  Monterrey   7937    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2590090-30  Reynosa 7938    Big Donuts  296 0
01/01/2012  2590090-30  Reynosa 7939    Big Donuts  12  0
01/01/2012  2590080-50  Saltillo    7941    Bigdonuts   64  0
01/01/2012  2590080-50  Saltillo    7942    Bigdonuts   38  0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7944    Bigdonuts   269 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7945    Bigdonuts   284 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7946    Bigdonuts   320 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7954    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7969    Bigdonuts   334 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7970    Bigdonuts   246 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7971    Bigdonuts   39  0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  7972    Bigdonuts   327 0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  8071    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2590080-50  Saltillo    8112    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2590080-50  Saltillo    8113    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2590080-50  Saltillo    8114    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2590080-50  Saltillo    8115    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2590080-50  Saltillo    8116    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2590080-50  Saltillo    8117    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  8212    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  8453    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  8454    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  8456    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2589970-20  Mexico  8457    Bigdonuts   0   0
01/01/2012  2590100-10  Monterrey   68895   Bigdonuts   0   0
```

Comment: Can you post the data in a couple of records that are missing?

Comment: By the way, in your query, you are joining the pedidoc table with the caducidad table, not Faltante.

Comment: I don't think the SQL statement in the question would actually execute as some of the fields in the `select` are not in the `group by` or part of an aggregate statement.

Comment: sorry that I mistyped the statement when I put it here, but it does execute, I will paste the table it gives for day 1 on the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
GROUP BY `pedidoc`.`fecha`, `pedidoc`.`IdProducto`
```

to

```
GROUP BY pedidoc.IdProducto, pedidoc.fecha, pedidoc.Plaza
```

so it matches your `UNIQUE` constraint on `pedidoc`, thereby ensuring that every row of `pedidoc` will appear exactly once.

(Note: your query, with or without this change, is not portable to other DBMSes, since it depends on special MySQL behavior; see [§12.17.3 "MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html). I'm assuming that's O.K.?)

Comment: Thanks!! That really solved the problem!! I am also very aware that it only works with MySQL and that I do not use some of the best practices of DBMS, but since I always use LAMP or WAMP, its good enough. I will probably migrate to a postgresql in a few months, but it will be rebuilt code-wise.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY is SUPPOSED to reduce the number of rows

I think you want ORDER BY

If you just want to eliminate the duplicate records, you could use SELECT DISTINCT.  Just add the DISTINCT keyword after the SELECT keyword, as described here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

However, I'm not certain whether that will give you what you want.  ruakh is right about this being a non-portable extension, and more importantly for you, as noted in the reference on ruakh's answer, the GROUP BY will group into one record all of the records whose values are the same for each of the fields in the GROUP BY.

For any fields mentioned in the SELECT which are NOT mentioned in the GROUP BY, MySQL will randomly pick any of the values for those fields in those records.  If all of those records have the same value for those fields, it will not matter which record is chosen.  For example, in your sample data above, Categoria is Bigdonuts for all of the first set of eight records with plaza of Mexico, so it doesn't matter which value of Categoria is chosen.

However, for Pedido, there are several different values shown, including 0, 406, and 425.  MySQL will randomly pick one of those eight different values.  I can't imagine that that is what you want.

That is why, in general, unless you know that all of records being grouped in a GROUP BY have the same values for a field, you will probably want to use one of the aggregate functions, like SUM, COUNT, etc.: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp

Comment: I used group by because for some reason the data was duplicated around 400 times. But I see your point, it may be part of the problem. But how can I achieve the LEFT JOIN without getting so many duplicates? should I change my database structure and input all the data again?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and completly agree with what you said, but for this case the Group by does the trick since I do not mind the non-portability. I already checked and all IdProducto appear in each plaza, each day, so while it may not be "tecnically" correct it is working.